# When will Netscape get es2015 support?

Tags: javascript

I'm a serious web developer and my client seriously needs Netscape, but there are some es2015 features I seriously need.

Thoughts?

[very serious]

Comment: This is a joke, right?

Comment: I suggest you get a new client.

Comment: What version of Netscape is your client using? Classic or Navigator?

Comment: "On 28 December 2007, the Netscape developers announced that AOL had canceled development of Netscape Navigator, leaving it unsupported as of 1 March 2008" aka, netscape will never have ES6 support.

Comment: Which features do you need, please list.

Comment: I really need block scoping in order to properly run on an old enterprise system; where all of the machines are running Netscape 7. There are a few other things like classes that would make life 1000x easier as well.

Comment: Tell your client to reunite with South Korea so they get access to recent technolgy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Babel.io https://babeljs.io/. It allows you to write es2015 and transforms the code to usable code for older browsers.

Comment: did NN7 support ES5? I highly doubt even babel would work there.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, ES5 became standard in 2009. I think NN7 only supports up to ES3 :(

Comment: Babel is a full blown Ecma-script parser, you could even manipulate the AST itself. But it is a large thing hence easier to just ask: what did not work with what code? What errors for a very simple block-scope and what for with `class`? Having to fight a lot of old and very old legacy code myself I do not regularly give up that early.